# Nested JSON with SQL OPENROWSET and OPENJSON

Tags: json, sql-server

I have multiple JSON files to parse into SQL, most of it I have been able to sort with OPENROWSET, OPENJSON and CROSS JOINS but there is one bit I am having trouble with.  A sample of the JSON:

```
{
    "MInfo": {
        "MName": "XGUA",
        "Instance": "1",
        "MAvailable": "Yes",
        "CB": "XG0A",
        "mo": "ENTRC"
    },
    "PG": [
        {
            "Name": "XI0BS.XI0SZE",
               "SIM": {
                "XGUA": {"XGUA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIM1": {"XIM1->XIM2_1": {"CC": ["XIM1","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIM2": {"XIM2->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIMA": {"XIMA->XIM2_1": {"CC": ["XIMA","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIIA": {"TIIA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["TIIA","TIQ2","XPD1","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}}
               }
        },
        {
            "Name": "D0549.XI0EXLA",
               "SIM": {
                "XGUA": {"XGUA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XGUA"],"value": [""]}}}},
        {
            "Name": "D0549.XI0EXTA",
               "SIM": {
                "XGUA": {"XGUA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XGUA"],"value": [""]}}}},
        {
            "Name": "EB0EB.CE1FA0",
               "SIM": {
                "IGR4": {"IGR4->XGN1_1": {"CC": ["IGR4","NGT1","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TQU7": {"TQU7->BEGIN": {"CC": ["TQU7","TQE2","FMSG","XIMZ","XIPK","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIH4": {"TIH4->TIX1_1": {"CC": ["TIH4","TIH5","SUB1","XPEN","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIS9": {"XIS9->XIS3_1": {"CC": ["XIS9","XGNP","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "FRI2": {"FRI2->FRI3_1": {"CC": ["FRI2","TIL2","TIMR","TIMQ","XPD1","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIDN": {"XIDN->XID3_1": {"CC": ["XIDN","FMSG","XIMZ","XIPK","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIV2": {"TIV2->TIV3_1": {"CC": ["TIV2","TIV3","NGT1","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TID2": {"TID2->TIDQ_1": {"CC": ["TID2","SLII","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "PNK2": {"PNK2->TOB1_1": {"CC": ["PNK2","PRP1","XCC0","XG0A","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIN4": {"TIN4->BEGIN": {"CC": ["TIN4","TIM3","XPD1","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}}, 
               }
        }
        }
    ],
}
```

I have parsed everything apart from the CC array, I am not sure how to return the elements in this array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

…

```
declare @j nvarchar(max) = N'
{
    "MInfo": {
        "MName": "XGUA",
        "Instance": "1",
        "MAvailable": "Yes",
        "CB": "XG0A",
        "mo": "ENTRC"
    },
    "PG": [
        {
            "Name": "XI0BS.XI0SZE",
               "SIM": {
                "XGUA": {"XGUA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIM1": {"XIM1->XIM2_1": {"CC": ["XIM1","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIM2": {"XIM2->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIMA": {"XIMA->XIM2_1": {"CC": ["XIMA","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIIA": {"TIIA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["TIIA","TIQ2","XPD1","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}}
               }
        },
        {
            "Name": "D0549.XI0EXLA",
               "SIM": {
                "XGUA": {"XGUA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XGUA"],"value": [""]}}}},
        {
            "Name": "D0549.XI0EXTA",
               "SIM": {
                "XGUA": {"XGUA->BEGIN": {"CC": ["XGUA"],"value": [""]}}}},
        {
            "Name": "EB0EB.CE1FA0",
               "SIM": {
                "IGR4": {"IGR4->XGN1_1": {"CC": ["IGR4","NGT1","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TQU7": {"TQU7->BEGIN": {"CC": ["TQU7","TQE2","FMSG","XIMZ","XIPK","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIH4": {"TIH4->TIX1_1": {"CC": ["TIH4","TIH5","SUB1","XPEN","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIS9": {"XIS9->XIS3_1": {"CC": ["XIS9","XGNP","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "FRI2": {"FRI2->FRI3_1": {"CC": ["FRI2","TIL2","TIMR","TIMQ","XPD1","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "XIDN": {"XIDN->XID3_1": {"CC": ["XIDN","FMSG","XIMZ","XIPK","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIV2": {"TIV2->TIV3_1": {"CC": ["TIV2","TIV3","NGT1","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TID2": {"TID2->TIDQ_1": {"CC": ["TID2","SLII","XIM2","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "PNK2": {"PNK2->TOB1_1": {"CC": ["PNK2","PRP1","XCC0","XG0A","XGUA"],"value": [""]}},
                "TIN4": {"TIN4->BEGIN": {"CC": ["TIN4","TIM3","XPD1","XIM0","XGUA"],"value": [""]}}
               }
        }   
    ]
}';


select isjson(@j);


select sim.[key], simv.[key], cc.value
from openjson(@j, N'$.PG') as pg
cross apply openjson(pg.value, N'$.SIM') as sim
cross apply openjson(sim.value) as simv
cross apply openjson(simv.value, N'$.CC') as cc;
```